# Add value to array if its not already in there

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to add a value to an array if its not already there.
So far my code looks something like this (note that both r.names and {name} are arrays, and `[1] + [2] = [1,2]`):

```
MERGE (r:resource {hash:{hash}})
ON CREATE SET r.names = {name}
ON MATCH SET r.names = r.names + {name}
```

but obviously if `{name}` is already in `r.names`, it just gets added again. How can I add `{name}` only if `r.names` doesn't already contain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you need to use the `FOREACH` + `CASE WHEN` trick: using a `case when` you use either a 1 element array (if your condition is true) or a 0 element array otherwise as iterator used in `FOREACH`. `FOREACH` cannot be used in a `ON MATCH` or `ON CREATE` handler, so we put it after the `MERGE` and use a `coalesce` to cover the case when r.names does not yet exist:

```
MERGE (r:Resource {hash:{hash}})
FOREACH(x in CASE WHEN {name} in r.names THEN [] ELSE [1] END | 
   SET r.names = coalesce(r.names,[]) + {name}
)
RETURN r.names
```

Comment: I wish i could give you more than 1 upvote and 1 like because this solution nailed it - thank you so much!
Only thing I would note for others following along is that in the above example the parameter {name} is just a string, not an array. If its an array it will appear not to work since {name} will not be in r.names. But thats an easy fix. Now all i have to do is figure out how the hell this even works :P

Comment: Just to verify, based on Stefans explanation, shouldn't it be THEN [1] ELSE [] instead?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FILTER`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-filter) to get an array of the elements that aren't already in `r.names` and add them:

```
MERGE (r:resource {hash:{hash}})
ON CREATE SET r.names = {new_names}
ON MATCH SET r.names = r.names + FILTER(
    el FOR el in {new_names} IF NOT el IN r.names
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of neo4j (as of v5.12), FILTER() has been deprecated. Instead use a list comprehension to return the original list + the new element, by intentionally removing the new element if it is already present. Use the following, where name is of type string:

```
MERGE (r:resource {hash:{hash}})
ON CREATE SET r.names = [name]
ON MATCH SET r.names = [name in r.names where name <> name] + [name]
```

This query will initialize a new list to r.names if r is created by the merge(), else it creates a new list containing all of the elements of r.names, expect for name. Then, name is appended.